# Backpack for Laravel - select from a table

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want a form where the user input as town and then selects a country. I have a table of countries. As we are in the create there is no relationship.

I cannot see how this can be done. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: create a new record for the town and store company id as a foreign key. 
 You enlightened? FYI asking a question like this is not going to help you here. At least share your code.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like the SELECT or SELECT2 field, which allows you to choose a related entry - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#select2-1-n-relationship